# Convert a week string to a date in MongoDB aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to parse a date string with a week number using `$dateFromString` in MongoDB aggregation pipelines?

For example, if you wanted to count objects in a collection grouped by week and then return the results with a timestamp from the beginning of that week.

```
{
  $group: {
    _id: { 
      $dateToString: { 
        format: '%Y-%V', 
        date: '$ts',
        timezone: 'Australia/Sydney'
      } 
    },
    count: { $sum: 1 }
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    count: 1,
    ts: {
      $dateFromString: {
        dateString: '$_id',
        format: '%Y-%V',
        timezone: 'Australia/Sydney'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Running this pipeline fails and returns the error;

> Error parsing date string '2019-30'; 7: Mixing of ISO dates with natural dates is not allowed

I also tried using the `%Y-%U` format, however `$dateFromString` does not support parsing this format.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually explained under [`$dateFromParts`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/) in the docs:

> You cannot combine the use of calendar dates and ISO week date fields when constructing your $dateFromParts input document.

Solution is to use the date format `%G-%V` (`%G` is the ISO 8601 year specifier).